# Use jQuery with $ and jQuery as prefix

Tags: jquery, prefix

In a very big project, we have several js-files with `$(` and `jQuery(` used as prefixes. We can't fix those files, because they are used in other projects too.

So is there a possibility to make jQuery respond to both prefixes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By default, jQuery uses **both** `$` and `jQuery` to refer to its function. It's only if you use [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) (or load another library) that that changes.

But if you're just loading jQuery and not doing anything to change it, this statement will be `true`:

```
console.log($ === jQuery); // "true"
```

---

FWIW, if for some reason you need to release the `$` symbol in your project, the files you have starting with:

```
$(function() {
```

can be modified like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
```

...and all the code within the `ready` function above can continue to use `$`, which shadows the global. jQuery passes a reference to its function into [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) handlers like that.

Comment: perfect answer and fast, I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to :)

Comment: @RaphaelJeger its strange you didn't have test it before posting your question

Comment: yeah, you are right @roasted, we posted without even thinking about it. Thank you for contributing